# Replace text with multiline pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a pattern in a file which includes a newline:

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
```

I want to set `enabled` to `true`. But the `enabled` has to be the one below
`client_encryption_options`.

grep doesn't allow me to search for multiline. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `grep` would additionally not allow you to make modifications, so that utility is out of the picture from the start.

Using GNU `sed` instead:

```
$ sed '/^client_encryption_options:/,+1s/enabled:.*/enabled: true/' file
```

This will find the line starting with the string `client_encryption_options:` and will apply a substitution to it and the following line.  The substitution will replace the string `enabled:` and everything following it on the same line with `enabled: true`.

The substitution will be applied to both lines, but since the pattern `enabled:.*` isn't found on the first line, it will remain unchanged.  The second line will be changed unconditionally (regardless of the text after `enabled:`).

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/client_encryption_options:/{n;s/false/true/;}'
```

`n` is the command to get the *next* line into the pattern space (after having printed and discarded the current pattern space content), `s` is to *substitute*.