# Using sed command to match text within a particular block of text

Tags: sed

I have the following text:

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    # If enabled and optional is set to true encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled.
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
```

I am trying to change the value in the keystore under client_encryption_options using the sed command.

```
sed "/^client_encryption_options:/,+1s/keystore:.*/keystore: \/opt\/test/" $CASSANDRA_YAML_FILE > cassandra.yaml.tmp && mv cassandra.yaml.tmp $CASSANDRA_YAML_FILE
```

When I try the above command it doesn't replace the conf/.keystore with `/opt/test/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

You're using my solution from [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344982/replace-text-with-multiline-pattern).  That question specifically asks about replacing a value on the next line.  This question requires you to make the change four lines further down.

Changing the `+1` to `+4` may fix it for you.

Comment: What if  i Want to search for the particular text. If the order changes that is

Comment: @user1692342 The substitution will be applied to all four lines (actually five, the one matching `^client_encryption_options:` and +4 more). As long as the pattern is unique, it will change the wanted line, no matter where amongst the four lines it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   /^client_encryption_options:/,/keystore:/!b
   //!b
   s|\(keystore:\).*|\1 /opt/test|
' < $CASSANDRA_YAML_FILE > cassandra.yaml.tmp && \
   mv cassandra.yaml.tmp "$CASSANDRA_YAML_FILE"
```

You can even use the '-i' (inplace edit) option if your 'sed' supports it to do away with the 'mv':

```
sed -i.BAK -e 'your edit commands here' $_YOUR_YAML_FILE # Note: NO redirections here
```